# Bijective Correspondence between Irreducible Subvarieties and Prime Ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $W \subset V$ be an irreducible subvariety of $V \subset A_{\mathbb{C}}^n$. Let $p \in V$. Prove that there is a  bijective correspondence between prime ideals in the local ring $O_{V,p}$ and $W$ with $p \in W$.

I am struggling proving that if $J \triangleleft O_{V,p}$ is prime then $W$ is an irreducible subvariety. Can I say that $J=J(V)$ where $p \in V$. I know that $J$ prime implies $V=V(J)$ is irreducible. So then all I would need to do is to restrict $J(V)$ to $J(W)$?

Comment: You say that you are having trouble proving $J$ prime implies $W$ irreducible, but you have not stated what correspondence you are using.  Given $J$, how do you obtain $W$?  (If you have not yet figured out how to construct $W$ from $J$, then this would be a good first step to solving the problem.)

Comment: Yes, I have not figured out how to construct W from J. Initially I thought that it would be just W(J), but then I am thinking that that is too simple.

Comment: Perhaps it would help you to work out the following algebraic fact: given a prime ideal $P$ in a commutative ring $R$, there is a bijective correspondence between the prime ideals of $R$ contained in $P$ and the prime ideals of the localization $R_P$.  The correspondence sends a prime $Q \subseteq P$ to $Q R_P$.